# Generating Spring DataAccessExceptions with legacy frameworks

Tags: java, spring, error-handling, rpc, corba

I'm currently rewriting a legacy web application where the backend is using, amongst other things CORBA and another RPC framework - both are quite old and do not have Spring support.

My hope is that I can eventually write a `@Repository` classes to handle the CORBA and other RPC calls and wrap all their exceptions with some flavor of `DataAccessException` which would then be thrown.

My questions are

1. is there a best practice for how to go about doing this so that my repositories don't throw too many `DataAccessExceptions` specifically in the area where both CORBA and RPC exceptions can be thrown by the same repository method?
2. should there be a class "below" the repository class to maybe handle some of this and abstract it away, or is that technically, what the repository class is for?

Comment: Does your repository work with different entity types? or just one?

Comment: different.  but I *think* they may all go through the same NameComponent name.  i wanted separate repos for each technology stack and may even go so far as to create repos for each CORBA object type I have to reference and autowire in the backend ORB/RPC code as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Given no responses from the community, I thought I'd post my implementation, which is by no means blessed and may even smell a bit.

In order for the code calling my business layer (classes marked with `@Service`) to only have to worry about one exception (namely `DataAccessException`) any/all exceptions thrown by code in the business layer or below gets wrapped into some form of `DataAccessException`.  The reason this smells funny is because business logic may legitimately throw exceptions that have nothing to do with data access, e.g., validation.

But, the idea was to not clutter up my servlets with multiple catch blocks or the anti-pattern of `try { ... } catch (Exception ex) { ... }`.

Again, not really an answer, but I suppose it does work...